# Incorrect Email validation hints

Tags: javascript, validation, email

I'm not a big fan of email validation regexes as I myself have come across a lot of sites that have too strict regexes and as a result have not been able to user my preferred email.

Basically I use only .+@.+ just to make sure they are not forgetting the @.

What I'd like to do though is to give the user hints if he/she has entered an email that LIKELY is incorrect. Like typos or weird characters.

So if they enter for instance mike3292@hotmaik.com then I can ask the user if he is sure, and maybe even hint to the right solution in some cases.

So basically what I want is to know if there is any existing source of top email providers and common spelling mistakes. Also maybe a regex for unusual characters to warn the user about, asking him to double check.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is really bad for validating emails. If you want to do a full/real validation you'll need a [very complicated expression](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

What I would recommend is to simply make sure it's `.*@.*\..*` which would check for `---@---.---` 
And have the user enter it twice.

It makes it easy for you, easy for the user, and not annoying. I wouldn't like it if a pop-up suggested my name was an invalid email address.

Comment: With custom top level domains registration opened by ICANN adresses like sergey@google isn't that far off.